# FireBase Database Rules tab Not Working

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When i Enter my Database and Click Rule tab its not Working its come back to Data Page [image]

Comment: Not a programming related question, post a bug report.

Comment: Check the JavaScript console of your browser for any errors. If there are any, post them here and/or include them in a [bug report](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've also reproduced the same bug, and I'm also clueless to what caused it. Below is a video recording of the page reverting back to Databases with a seemingly messed-up URL (`project_name` is doubled).

[Firebase Rules Bug on Chrome (Incognito)](https://youtu.be/wqE9dR6bmA4)

I'm not sure if the following could have contributed to the bug reproduction but the past days prior to this I have been actively:

1. Editing and publishing rules for the said database via the web Firebase Console
2. Switching to (2) workstations: an office workstation and a personal notebook at home (while using android studio), copying only updated relevant source codes from one workstation to another and vice-versa.

I have also filed a bug report, will update later with answers. Also looking forward for expert advice on workarounds for this bug if somebody out there have gotten around this. TIA! :)

### **------ UPDATE: ------**

I'm still waiting response for the bug's official fix, but I found out the that the rules can still be accessed in other ways, other than than this thread's buggy Firebase Web Console Rules tab.

**Current means for accessing Firebase Rules:**

- Firebase Web Console [Rules](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/fir-web-87a9b/database/fir-web-87a9b/rules) tab (buggy)
- [Firebase CLI](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools) (firebase-tools)
- [Managing Firebase Realtime Database Rules via REST](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/app-management)

While the rules tab on the web console is an easy and straight-forward approach for editing the database's rules, for the meantime we can switch to using firebase CLI until the bug is resolved. I find this to be most straightforward for **viewing** and **updating** rules.

**(Inserting a quick guide to using firebase-tools for updating rules.json)**

1. Install the latest [nodejs and npm](https://nodejs.org/en/) binaries (v.9.1.0 as of this writing)
2. Install [firebase-tools](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools): `> npm install -g firebase-tools`
3. Login to your firebase account: `> firebase login`
4. Initialize firebase features to use: `> firebase init`
5. Select `Database: Deploy Firebase Realtime Database Rules`
6. Load the (buggy) project's rules: select your bugged firebase project, and press enter.
7. `Open database.rules.json` to view and/or edit your project's (inaccessible) rules.json
8. Commit your changes your database's online rules: `> firebase deploy --only database`

### **------ UPDATE ------**

Hi all, I just wanted to share that the firebase support team has just released the bug's fix to public. Firebase rules tab on my console is accessible once more.